# How is ForEach activity declaring success in Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, etl, azure-data-factory

In the following scenario we have a `ForEach` activity running in an `Azure Data Factory` pipeline to copy data from source to destination.
The last `CopyActivity` took 4:10:33 but the `ForEach` activity declared Succeeded 36 Minutes later: 4:46:12.
The question is, why `ForEach` activity need this 36 Minutes extra?
Is it the case that the `ForEach` needs also to consolidate results from subactivities before declaring success or fail?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Official answer from Microsoft:** ForEach activity does wait for all inner activity runs to complete. In theory, there should not be much delay on marking foreach run success after the last activity run within it succeed. However, ADF rely on partner service to execute the runs and it's possible that the partner service run into failures and could not complete foreach in time. They have build in logic to keep retry and recover but the behavior in ADF activity runs is delay. It's also possible that orchestration service fails and partner service keep retry on calling us. but usually partner service delay is the main cause here.

**Our assumption:** `Duration time` is end-to-end for the pipeline activity. That takes into account all factors like marshaling of your data flow script from ADF to the Spark cluster, cluster acquisition time, job execution, and I/O write time. Due to ADF is serverless compute, I think `ForEach` needs time to wait for all activities to acquire and release computing resources, but this is my guess because there are few official explanations.

So there will be a delay time, which varies according to internal activities.
[image]

Comment: Xu, I think you are right, these are also my thoughts and seems legitim. Couldn't find anything official in this direction.

Comment: Yes,  otherwise we can’t explain where the time went, haha.

Comment: also posted below an official answer from Microsoft. Our assumption was also correct

Answer (score 1):

**Official answer from Microsoft**: ForEach activity does wait for all inner activity runs to complete. In theory, there should not be much delay on marking foreach run success after the last activity run within it succeed. However, ADF rely on partner service to execute the runs and it's possible that the partner service run into failures and could not complete foreach in time. They have build in logic to keep retry and recover but the behavior in ADF activity runs is delay. It's also possible that orchestration service fails and partner service keep retry on calling us. but usually partner service delay is the main cause here.